# ngnix on amazon ec2 instance which has RedHat 4.4.4-13?

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance running on amazon which has AMI(ami-1b814f72).Its running  RedHat 4.4.4-13 version.

I want to install ngnix and gunicorn on with django. According to ngnix http://wiki.nginx.org/Install#Official_Red_Hat.2FCentOS_packages page I need to create a file `/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo` and paste those line for finding repo.But they also mentioned that :

> Due to differences between how CentOS, RHEL, and Scientific Linux
>   populate the $releasever variable, it is necessary to manually replace
>   $releasever with either "5" (for 5.x) or "6" (for 6.x), depending upon
>   your OS version.

But I don't have either 5 or 6 version. I have RedHat 4.4.4-13 version, so what should I do in that case to make it work and get installed ngnix on my ec2 instance.

If I dont change the baseurl and try to install ngnix I got this error:

> http://nginx.org/packages/rhel/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
>   [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
>   Trying other mirror. Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata
>   (repomd.xml) for repository: ngnix. Please verify its path and try
>   again

**Please note: I want to be under AWS free Usage Tier and I don't want to be get charged**

I hope someone will help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved my own problem and writing answer to my own QUESTION.Their is no available ngnix package for RHEL 4.4.Either we build from source specifically for RHEL 4.4 or just migrate to an updated version of AMI on amazon.I moved to ubuntu 11.10 which is updated one and currently supported by ubuntu community.